# Dropzone not uploading file to local folder

Tags: php, html, dropzone

I am attempting to do is to upload an image to a local folder, using Dropzone. However, the image is not loaded (moved) to the local folder. This is drop & drag version.

Just followed the code from a tutorial.
I am using XAMPP, Windows 10, and Chrome.
php.ini is set to upload files.

The form:

```
<!--dropzone form -->
<form action="uploads.php" class="dropzone" id="avatar-dropzone">
     <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" />
     </div>
</form>
```

The initialization code:

```
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#avatar-dropzone");
    });

  </script>
```

The file is supposed to appear in a local folder called uploads, but no files appear here.

I include an image of the directory structure with relevant folders/files marked:

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZB7I.jpg)

The uploads.php code:

```
<?php
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $storeFolder = '../uploads'; 

        if (!empty($_FILES)) {

            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];             

            $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

       }

?>
```

The form and the initialization code are in the views/users.php page.
The upload folder in the project folder
The uploads.php is in the admin folder
The js/css links are in config/js & config/css

I can drag an image, but nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to debug your php code. I would make few modifications:

```
    ...
    $storeFolder = dirname( __DIR__ ).'/uploads/'; 

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];             

        //$targetPath =  $storeFolder; // <-- we don't need this line anymore

        $targetFile =  $storeFolder . $_FILES['file']['name'];

        die($targetFile); // <-- just debug if your filename is correct and if you ever reach this point.
   ...
```

Another thing to check is permissions on `$storeFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried the above code and finding that it did not work, I looked at the folders to make sure I was linking to the correct one.  It was then I discovered I had misnamed the file. Instead of uploads.php i had uploads..php.  I correct this and it now works.  Will keep both version of the uploads.php code for reference.

My thanks to alex for the help.